# Escape double quotes in json functions mysql

Tags: mysql, json, rdbms, json-query

I know it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to escape the double quotes inside mysql query for json manipulation.

I have the following example:

```
SET @j = '{"4": 1, "0as@x"" : [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [2, 3]}';
```

Please pay attention to the double quotes inside the second key: `0as@x"`

If i run this query: `SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@j, '$."0as@x\"', '2');`
I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_array_append: "Missing a colon after a name of object member." at position 16.
```

All I want is to know how to escape the double quotes inside variable name of json object key.

I also have tried doubling the quotes `"""`, with two backslashes `\\"`...

Could you please help me?

Thank you!

**Later EDIT**

In the set statement I escaped the double quotes with `\"`. This is done behind if you use `JSON_OBJECT`.

In the end I escaped with `\\` the double quotes and it worked.

The final code that is **working**:

```
SET @j = JSON_OBJECT('4', 1, '0as@x"', '[1, 2, 3, 4]', 'b', '[2, 3]');
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@j, '$."0as@x\\""',  2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSON_OBJECT function to build the object, this way:

```
SET @j = JSON_OBJECT('4', 1, '0as@x"', '[1, 2, 3, 4]', 'b', '[2, 3]');
```

Then the function (no extra quotes around the key name):

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@j, '$.0as@x"',  2);
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: the code generates error... i think you can't start a variable's name with a digit, i tried though `SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@j, '$."0as@x\\""',  2);` and it worked

Comment: ok, yes your answer made me think that json_object escapes the characters and that's why my initial set was doing something different from what I expected. Thank you very much!